# Clear a DynamoDb trigger iterator

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Is it possible to "purge"/"clear" the iterator of a dynamoDb table's trigger ?

**Context:**
A lambda is processing updates on a given table using a trigger.
Badly formatted records are inserted in the table and the lamdba is unable to process it, stalling the iterator.
A few time after a fix is issued to insert correctly formatted records in the table. So we want to "fast forward" the processing of updates and skip the old ones?

I suppose deleting/recreating the trigger would do that. Is there a "better" way ?

Comment: There is no easy way to fast-forward.... Other options would be to temporarily update lambda code to just read records and don't do anything or wait 24 hours for the bad records to clear out

Comment: Another way is to let the context succeed. What I mean is, modify the lambda function which is being triggered to return true, until the trigger status shows OK.

After that clear the table, and re-instate the lambda to its original implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but this can help somebody else:
as stated in the comments, I don't think it's possible to simply purge the queue.

However, when you re-create it, you can chose the "starting position" between:

- "Latest" (will skip all previously stored messages)
- "Trim horizon" (will process all the available messages)

Re-creating the trigger is pretty easy, that's what I have done in a similar case recently